# object function loop override javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm very confused about the following code :

```
 var x =[ {name : 'name1' , value : 15 },{name :'name2' , value: 60} ];
 var y = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]] ; 
     for(var t in y){
         x[t].myFun = function(){console.log(y[t])} ;
      }
 console.log(x[0].myFun()) ;
```

shouldn't this code return  the first array in `y` why does it return the second array ?

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/y6yxZ/)

Comment: Just a heads-up the for-in loops are for iterating over members in an object. Use for(var i=0; i < anArray.length; i++){anArray[i]} to iterate over an array.

Comment: The actual problem lies in `console.log(y[t])`, since the value of `t` in the function will always be equal to the last it had (ie 1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `myFun` functions all reference the *same* `t` (and `y`) variable.  So after the loop, `t` is `1`, so it always returns the 2nd value.

You need to use a closure to "close" around the values (also, you shouldn't use `for..in` for arrays):

```
var x = [{name : 'name1' , value : 15 }, {name :'name2' , value: 60}];
var y = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]]; 
for(var t = 0, len = y.length; t < len; t++){
    (function(t){
        x[t].myFun = function(){console.log(y[t])};
    })(t);
}

console.log(x[0].myFun());
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using JQuery, you have a simple method to iterate arrays without the needing to worry about specifically capturing the current value of your index when creating a closure. It's `$.each`:

```
var x =[ {name : 'name1' , value : 15 },{name :'name2' , value: 60} ];
var y = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]] ; 
$.each(y, function(i,v)
{
    x[i].myFun = function(){console.log(y[i])} ;
});
```

Comment: Heck, you can probably even use `v` instead of `y[i]`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Right! `v` will be equal to `y[i]`.